# Protect admin with roles

Tags: symfony, roles, access-control

I want only users have **ADMIN** or **ENSEIGNANT** roles can access to the admin part but still I get **Access Denied** even when I authenticate as **ENSEIGNANT**

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:      [ROLE_ENSEIGNANT]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

//...........


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ENSEIGNANT] }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are giving an `ENSEIGNANT` to user not `ROLE_ENSEIGNANT`, but your access control is checking against `ROLE_ENSEIGNANT`, that's why you're getting an Access denied exception. Try to change `getRoles` method to return `ROLE_ENSEIGNANT` if there's any..

Comment: Yes ti was because I give it ENSEIGNANT not a ROLE_ENSEIGNANT. thank you very much